# Using ExtAudioFileWriteAsync() in callback function. Can't get to run

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-audio

Just can't seem to get very far in Core Audio. My goal is to write captured audio data from an instrument unit to a file. I have set up a call to a callback function on an instrument unit with this:

```
CheckError(AudioUnitAddRenderNotify(player->instrumentUnit,
                                    MyRenderProc,
                                    &player),
           "AudioUnitAddRenderNotify Failed");
```

I set up the file and AudioStreamBasicDescription with this:

```
#define FILENAME @"output_IV.aif"

NSString *fileName = FILENAME; // [NSString stringWithFormat:FILENAME_FORMAT, hz];
NSString *filePath = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] currentDirectoryPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: fileName];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: filePath];
NSLog (@"path: %@", fileURL);

AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd;
memset(&asbd, 0, sizeof(asbd));
asbd.mSampleRate = 44100.0;
asbd.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
asbd.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsBigEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
asbd.mChannelsPerFrame = 2; // CHANGED FROM 1 (STEREO)
asbd.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
asbd.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
asbd.mBytesPerFrame = 4;
asbd.mBytesPerPacket = 4;

CheckError(ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)fileURL, kAudioFileAIFFType, &asbd, NULL, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, &testRecordFile), "ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL failed"); 
CheckError(ExtAudioFileSetProperty(testRecordFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, (UInt32)sizeof(asbd), &asbd), "ExtAudioFileSetProperty failed"); 
CheckError(ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(testRecordFile, 0, NULL), "ExtAudioFileWriteAsync 1st time failed");
```

I verified that the file does get created. testRecordFile is defined globally (it's the only way I could get things to run at the moment):

```
ExtAudioFileRef testRecordFile;
```

My callback function is:

```
OSStatus MyRenderProc(void *inRefCon,
                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                  UInt32 inBusNumber,
                  UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                  AudioBufferList * ioData)
{
    if (*ioActionFlags & kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRender){
    static int TEMP_kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRenderError = (1 << 8);
        if (!(*ioActionFlags & TEMP_kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRenderError)){
            CheckError(ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(testRecordFile, inNumberFrames, ioData), "ExtAudioFileWriteAsync failed");
        }
    }
return noErr;
}
```

When I run this the program pinwheels and goes into debugger mode (lldb) on the ExtAudioFileWriteAsync call. inNumberFrames = 512 and I have verified that I am getting stereo channels of Float32 audio data in ioData.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code is still slightly complicated, and including some of "dark corners" of CoreAudio and Obj-C. It is a safer bet first making sure that everything works as intended in plain-C, on the real-time thread. As soon as you have debugged that part of code you can easily add as much Obj-C elegance as needed.

If ignoring possible endianness and file format conversion issues for simplicity, there is still *one issue* you either have to resolve automatically, using API utilities, or "manually":

AFAIK, data format for `ExtAudioFileWriteAsync()` must be interleaved, while the stream format for your AUGraph is *not*. Assuming we don't deal with endiannes and format conversion here, this is how you can fix it manually (single-channel example). In case your `asbd` stream format is non-interleaved stereo, you interleave data in your buffer like this: LRLRLRLRLR...

```
OSStatus MyRenderProc(void *inRefCon, 
                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                  UInt32 inBusNumber,
                  UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                  AudioBufferList * ioData) 
{
AudioBufferList bufferList;
Float32 samples[inNumberFrames+inNumberFrames];

bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = samples;
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = (inNumberFrames+inNumberFrames)*sizeof(Float32);
Float32 *data = (Float32 *)ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;

if (*ioActionFlags & kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRender){
    static int TEMP_kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRenderError = (1 << 8);
    if (!(*ioActionFlags & TEMP_kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRenderError) {  
        for(UInt32 i = 0; i < inNumberFrames; i++)
            samples[i+i] = samples [i+i+1] = data[i];//copy buffer[0] to L & R            
        ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(testRecordFile, inNumberFrames, &bufferList);
    }
}
return noErr;
}
```

This is just one example to show how it works. By studying `asbd.mFormatFlags` and setting the proper format in:

```
ExtAudioFileSetProperty(testRecordFile,
                        kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat,
                        s,
                        &asbd);
```

you can achieve it more elegantly, but this exceeds the scope you this post by far.

Comment: That makes sense. I took the bait by the match between ioData in the callback template and ExtAudioFileWriteAsync. My code will be more extensive since I am writing to .aif but I get the idea. Thanks!

Comment: I analyzed your code - in this example I'm using CAF instead of AIF on purpose, because I wanted this example to be clear and helpful to everyone. Apple made a bit of mess with AIFF standard on Intel machines, declaring a _native little-endian_ Linear PCM version of AIFF as byte-swapped twos complement subtype of AIFC (aka. SOWT), and furtherly mystifying  the format by unifying AIFF and AIFC standards into "AIF". Take care.

Comment: It worked! Thanks again so much. I hope I can return the karma someday to someone when I am more experienced in all of this. For future reference I will include the working code for AIF below. Cheers!

Comment: Glad it worked. Thanks for posting your code. Please edit it -the first sentence should be specific: "Here's the working callback for a 16-bit linear big-endian stereo AIF file."

Answer (score 1):

Here's the working callback for a 16-bit linear big-endian stereo AIF file:

```
OSStatus MyRenderProc(void *inRefCon,
                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                  UInt32 inBusNumber,
                  UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                  AudioBufferList * ioData)
{
    SInt16 samples[inNumberFrames + inNumberFrames];
    AudioBufferList bufferList;
    bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = samples;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = (inNumberFrames + inNumberFrames) * sizeof(SInt16);

    Float32 *leftData = (Float32 *)ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;
    Float32 *rightData = (Float32 *)ioData->mBuffers[1].mData;

    if (*ioActionFlags & kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRender){
        static int TEMP_kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRenderError = (1 << 8);
        if (!(*ioActionFlags & TEMP_kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRenderError)){
            for (UInt32 i = 0; i < inNumberFrames; i++) {
                samples[i + i] = CFSwapInt16HostToBig((SInt16) SHRT_MAX * (leftData)[i]);
                samples[i + i + 1] = CFSwapInt16HostToBig((SInt16) SHRT_MAX * (rightData)[i]);
            }
        CheckError(ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(testRecordFile, inNumberFrames, &bufferList), "ExtAudioFileWriteAsync failed");
        }
    }
    return noErr;
}
```