# iOS kAudioFileUnsupportedDataFormatError while creating Audio File for recording

Tags: ios, swift, audio-recording, audiotoolbox

I am using `ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL` and consistently get a runtime `kAudioFileUnsupportedDataFormatError` error when creating a Stereo LPCM Float32 Wave file. I insist that the same procedure works fine with a Mono (single channel) file. Any hints?

Here's the code snippet:

```
let audioType: AudioFileTypeID = kAudioFileWAVEType 
var recordingFormatStream = CAStreamBasicDescription(sampleRate: sampleRate, numChannels: 2, pcmf: .Float32, isInterleaved: false)!

err = ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(audioFileRecordingURL,
                                    audioType,
                                    &recordingFormatStream,
                                    nil,
                                    AudioFileFlags.EraseFile.rawValue,
                                    &audioRecordingAudioFile)
```

noting that `audioFileRecordingURL` and `audioRecordingAudioFile` are correctly typed and set.

For the records, the `recordingFormatStream` contains:

```
mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved
mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM
mSampleRate: 44100.0
mBytesPerPacket: 4, mFramesPerPacket: 1, mBytesPerFrame: 4, mChannelsPerFrame: 2, mBitsPerChannel: 32, mReserved: 0
```

I insist that if I change the `numChannels` to 1, everything is fine! Using iOS 9.3 SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much struggle: The `ExtAudioFile` methods in SDK **do not accept non-interleaved audio**. I believe that this is somehow new!

Thanks to this post: [Using ExtAudioFileWriteAsync() in callback function. Can't get to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37670071/using-extaudiofilewriteasync-in-callback-function-cant-get-to-run)